# Amazon MWS Inventory Add Quantity (increment/decrement instead of setting Quantity)

Tags: amazon-mws

Is there a way (feed) to increase/decrease the inventory quantity instead of setting  quantity to an absolute value ?

So instead of

```
<Quantity>100</Quantity>         => set to inventory qty to 100
```

use e.g. something like this (incr/decr)

```
<AddQuantity>10</AddQuantity>    => add 10 to inventory qty
```

or

```
<Quantity>+10</Quantity>         => add 10 to inventory qty
```

Is there any feed or other possibility to do this in MWS ?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such API - you will have to calculate the new quantity yourself.

You could, however, get an inventory report through MWS first to determine the current quantity in stock (call `RequestReport` to get a `_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_`)

Sidenote: I find it a bit awkward that Amazon seems to know more about your quantities in stock than your own software...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We use this report already. Sometimes thing are more complex then they appear on the the first look..... (e.g. to synchronize stock in severals systems)